# Como retornar o id do usuário que esta na sessão

Tags: php, query, pdo, session, id

```
require_once('conexao.php');
@$email = $_POST['email'];
@$senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
// $email = "renan-ano10@bol.com.br";
// $senha = "12346";

$pdo = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT userid, nome, nivel FROM usuario WHERE email=:email and senha=:senha");
$pdo->bindParam(":email", $email);
$pdo->bindParam(":senha", $senha);
$pdo->execute();
// print_r ($pdo);

$users = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($users) <= 0)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Email ou senha errados');
                top.location.href='./index.php';
                </script>";
    exit;
}

// pega o primeiro usuário
$user = $users[0];

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['userid'] = $user['userid'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['nome'];
$_SESSION['usernivel'] = $user['nivel'];
// print_r ($_SESSION);
// echo session_id();

header('Location: ./_link/link.php');
```

Quero retornar o `id` em outra página para fazer um `insert` no banco

```
session_start();
  print_r($_SESSION);
if(!$_SESSION) {
    header("Location: .././index.php");
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: quem seria esse id?

Comment: O id da tabela usuário, que puxei para a sessão. Em outra página quero vincular o usuário para que ele faça o insert no banco de dados

Comment: seria o valor de  `userid`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quero que a outra pagina receba esse id para o insert ser vinculado a esse usuário

Comment: Você já possui o valor dele, `$_SESSION['userid']` coloque isso em uma variavel na pagina do insert  `$variavel = $_SESSION['userid']` não esqueça do `session_start();`

Comment: Note que `$_SESSION` mostra todos os valores de variáveis ​​de sessão para uma sessão de usuário

Answer (score 1):

Para ter acesso às variáveis de sessão criadas, use as chaves que utilizou para colocar dados na sessão:

- `$_SESSION['logged_in']`
- `$_SESSION['userid']`
- `$_SESSION['username']`
- `$_SESSION['usernivel']`

Se fizer:

```
echo $_SESSION['userid']
```

Verá que tem acesso ao dado `userid` que colocou na sessão. Porém, é necessário garantir que o primeiro bloco de código seja executado antes de chamar a variável de sessão e garantir que não foi destruída.

Comment: Eu verei, tu verás, ele verá.

Comment: Nessa página funciona, quero fazer em outra página entende